# How to work generically with overridden method parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I need to replace 229 occurrences of an older CSLA data access class, the first step is to place really clean shim code with the least amount of testable changes. I almost got there and was trying to do this without having to decorate all `BusinessClass` descendants with an interface as a way to force `Fetch_Data`.

Each class descending from `BusinessBase` will implement it's own `Fetch_Data` by overriding. I have most of it working, however, you can't override a method using a parameter descending from a class that is used in the virtual version, the method signature is different and the compiler will not allow it.

Any hints on how to make the chain below work without interfaces, specifically how to work generically with the criteria below?

```
public class BusinessLayerBaseNoCSLA<T>
{
    public virtual void Fetch_Data(BaseParameters parameters){ throw new NotWellConfiguredException();
}
```

Extending BusinessLayerBase:

```
public class Vehicle : BusinessLayerBaseNoCSLA<Vehicle>
{
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }

    public override void Fetch_Data(GetVehicleParameters parameters)//<--This line has a red squiggly because of the signature difference, no suitable method found to override.
    {
        //I could cast like  var p = (GetVehicleParameters)BaseParameters; here but something smells bad about that  
        GetVehicleParameters p = parameters;
        ... 
        VehicleId = p.VehicleId;
    }
}
```

`DataPortal` is using static to avoid newing up and calling `Fetch`, condenses to one line of code.

```
public static class DataPortal
{
    public static T FetchData<T>(object criteria) where T : BusinessLayerBaseNoCSLA<T>, new()
    {
        var result = new T();
        result.Fetch_Data((BaseParameters)criteria);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Desired usage

```
var Vehicle = DataPortal.FetchData<Vehicle>(new GetVehicleParameters({ VehicleId =1 });
```

Comment: Why not something like `Fetch_Data<TParameter>(TParameter parameters) where T: BaseParameters`?

Comment: I do this another way using CSLA 3.5. We have a Database Factory class that derives from BusinessBase, this way you only need a dozen changes instead of refactoring 230. Plus I would steer clear of modifying CSLA directly as this will impact upgrades. Also given the SimplePortal CSLA DAL is 7 callstacks deep one more won't hurt. Unless removing this bloat/overhead is the aim?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Maybe I am doing something wrong, however, when I change BusinessLayerBaseNoCSLA.Fetch_Data() to use a generic type, the compiler is expecting the overriding version to be decorated with <TParameter> as well, I cant use a class type for TParameter in the override :( It says no suitable methods to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want specifically typed parameters to your `Fetch_Data(BaseParameters parameters)` method, you could introduce the fetch parameters as a generic type to your base class.

BusinessLayerBaseNoCSLA would become:

```
public class BusinessLayerBaseNoCSLA<TObject, TParameters>
    where TObject : BusinessLayerBaseNoCSLA<TObject, TParameters> // optional
    where TParameters : BaseParameters
{
    public virtual void Fetch_Data(TParameters parameters)
    {
        throw new NotWellConfiguredException();
    }
}
```

Vehicle would be defined as:

```
public class Vehicle : BusinessLayerBaseNoCSLA<Vehicle, GetVehicleParameters>
{
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }

    public override void Fetch_Data(GetVehicleParameters parameters)
    {
        //I could cast like  var p = (GetVehicleParameters)BaseParameters; here but something smells bad about that  
        // Note: No need to cast 'parameters' here!
        GetVehicleParameters p = parameters;            
        VehicleId = p.VehicleId;
    }
}
```

DataPortal is re-defined as:

```
public static class DataPortal
{
    public static TObject FetchData<TObject, TParameters>(TParameters criteria) 
        where TObject : BusinessLayerBaseNoCSLA<TObject, TParameters>, new()
        where TParameters : BaseParameters
    {
        var result = new TObject();
        //result.Fetch_Data((BaseParameters)criteria);
        // Note: no need to cast criteria!
        result.Fetch_Data(criteria);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Vehicle vehicle = DataPortal.FetchData<Vehicle, GetVehicleParameters>(new GetVehicleParameters() { VehicleId = 1 });
// Note: we need to explicitly call the FetchData<,> with the correct types
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking down these lines as well. The only drawback to this approach is that the Vehicle class would be bound to one specific parameter set, whereas, I need to allow multiple criteria for selecting data..